# How to call Activities in DummyFragment?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making application where almost everything happens with sliding so I made every activity being based on pre-build solution for Navigation Type: Tabs or Tabs + Swipe which can be seen here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html . In that solution, I couldn't pass the instance of Activity to Fragment called DummyFragment, which I needed to start new Activity, so I was always using static methods to get instance of an Activity. Now when my application got bigger and more complicated, I have already like 30 Activities, all with static method to retrieve its instance. I feel that it's really bad solution to make it like that because I think that what I make static, always stays in memory, even if application is not active and I wouldn't like to kill the performance of the device.

How should I solve this to have optimal performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your fragment, invoke `getActivity()` to access the hosting activity.